# How to remove sf form warning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, javascript, javascript-controller

I have this lightning component recordEditForm -

```
<lightning:recordEditForm
      aura:id="crearAgenteForm"
      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
      onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"
      objectApiName="Agente__c"
      class="slds-theme_default">
```

The form shows me the warning when I add the wrong parameter field, and I don't program this warning. I don't know where this warning comes from, anyone knows how to remove it?
This is the handleSubmit function in the controller component:

```
    ({
  handleSubmit: function(component, event, helper) {
    if ("c.handleSubmit") {
      var validacionRut = /^\d{1,2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}[-][0-9kK]{1}$/;
      var rutCompleto = component.get("v.Agente__c.RUT__c");
      if (!rutCompleto.toString().match(validacionRut)) {
        return false;
      } else {
        console.log("HanddleSubmit");
        console.log("Call helper component");
        helper.insert(component, event);
          return true;
      } 
    }
  }
});
```

And this is the warning -
[image: warning image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message might be added because of `<lightning:messages />` tag in form?

Look at the section to [override the default behavior](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation), it says:

> To customize the behavior of your form when it loads or when data is submitted, use the onload and onsubmit attributes to specify event handlers. **If you capture the submit event and submit the form programmatically, use event.preventDefault() to cancel the default behavior of the event.** This prevents a duplicate form submission.

Try using `event.preventDefault()` in submit method.

Comment: that's work, thanks